# I don't understand testing with savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

I'm looking at the testing docs for Savon [here](http://savonrb.com/version2/testing.html) and i don't understand what's going on. I'm fairly new to testing with mocks and stubbing and maybe that's the issue. Here is the example:

```
require "spec_helper"

# require the helper module
require "savon/mock/spec_helper"

describe AuthenticationService do
  # include the helper module
  include Savon::SpecHelper

  # set Savon in and out of mock mode
  before(:all) { savon.mock!   }
  after(:all)  { savon.unmock! }

  describe "#authenticate" do
    it "authenticates the user with the service" do
      message = { username: "luke", password: "secret" }
      fixture = File.read("spec/fixtures/authentication_service/authenticate.xml")

      # set up an expectation
      savon.expects(:authenticate).with(message: message).returns(fixture)

      # call the service
      service = AuthenticationService.new
      response = service.authenticate(message)

      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
end
```

I understand that we set up an expectation with the fixture i.e. what the response should be.

We then call the service and get a response. My questions are:
1. Is a real call being made?
2. Is this response a real response??
3. Can someone try to explain this overall for me please?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

No remote request would be made.  Since you have mocked `authenticate`, the response will be short-circuited to your designated value.  However, some other preliminary requests might be expected to happen first, like a GET for the WSDL.

Comment: I am currently working on a very similar project, could you elaborate more on your answer please @Joe Atzberger

Comment: `savon.expects(:authenticate)...` is like an rspec `expect` statement.  Therefore, savon will not actually authenticate remotely.  `savon.mock!` means it won't connect for anything.  The page linked to in OP (where this example comes from) goes into greater detail: http://savonrb.com/version2/testing.html

Comment: Alright,but do you think this a better alternative to using webmock  or vcr gem?

Comment: We used it in combination with VCR.